# How to see external links using Google Search Console (new version)?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks

I used to be able to see the external links pointing to my website using Google Search Console, [image from here](https://ahrefs.com/blog/who-links-to-my-site/):

[image]

I believe Google has updated the Web Master and I am not sure how to see the external links in their new Version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was mistakenly looking at the wrong property (same website without www):

[image]

I can see the links now that I am in the correct property.